# Adding Subview to UICollectionViewCell Subclass?

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I seem to be having trouble adding a subview to a view within my `UICollectionViewCell` subclass.

I have an abstract `UICollectionViewCell` subclass titled `MessageItem`, which looks like this:

[image]

I've created a few classes that inherit from this (since they all use the same logic for the header and footer). However I can't seem to add any subviews into `MessageItem`'s blue view from within the child subclasses.

For example one of the child views is called `TextItem`. I'm trying to add a label to it's parent messageView (the blue view) but it only works if I do it in my UIViewController's `cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method, and not in my custom subclass.

This is how I'm trying to add it in my child subclass:

```
- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {

    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {

        //Setup Message Label
        [self setupMessageLabel];
    }

    return self;
}

#pragma mark - Setup Methods

- (void)setupMessageLabel {

    NSLog(@"Setting up label");

    //Setup Message Label
    self.messageLabel = [TTTAttributedLabel new];
    self.messageLabel.verticalAlignment = TTTAttributedLabelVerticalAlignmentCenter;
    self.messageLabel.textInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(8, 8, 8, 8);
    self.messageLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    [self.messageContentView addSubview:self.messageLabel];
    [self.messageContentView autoPinEdgesToSuperviewEdges];

    //Update Label Color
    self.messageLabel.backgroundColor = FlatRed;
}
```

Note: I'm not using storyboard or xibs. Could that be the problem?

## Update

This is what my `MessageItem` class is implemented:

**MessageItem.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class Message;

@interface MessageItem : UICollectionViewCell

@property (nonatomic, strong) Message *message;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *messageContentView;

@end
```

**MessageItem.m**

```
@interface MessageItem ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) TTTAttributedLabel *headerLabel;
@property (nonatomic, strong) TTTAttributedLabel *footerLabel;

@end

@implementation MessageItem
@synthesize message = _message;

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {

    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {

        //Setup Main View
        [self setupMainView];
    }

    return self;
}

#pragma mark - Setup Methods

- (void)setupMainView {

    //Setup Header
    [self setupHeaderLabel];

    //Setup Message
    [self setupMessageView];

    //Setup Footer View
    [self setupFooterLabel];
}

- (void)setupHeaderLabel {

    //Setup Header Label
    self.headerLabel = [[TTTAttributedLabel alloc] initForAutoLayout];
    self.headerLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Lato-Bold" size:12.0];
    self.headerLabel.textColor = FlatGray;
    self.headerLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    self.headerLabel.verticalAlignment = TTTAttributedLabelVerticalAlignmentCenter;
    self.headerLabel.textInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 8, 0, 8);
    self.headerLabel.backgroundColor = FlatPurple;
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.headerLabel];
    [self.headerLabel autoSetDimension:ALDimensionHeight toSize:20.0];
    [self.headerLabel autoPinEdgesToSuperviewEdgesWithInsets:UIEdgeInsetsZero excludingEdge:ALEdgeBottom];
}

- (void)setupMessageView {

    //Setup Message View
    self.messageContentView = [UIView new];
    self.messageContentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.messageContentView];
    [self.messageContentView autoSetDimension:ALDimensionHeight toSize:30 relation:NSLayoutRelationGreaterThanOrEqual];
    [self.messageContentView autoPinEdgeToSuperviewEdge:ALEdgeLeading];
    [self.messageContentView autoPinEdgeToSuperviewEdge:ALEdgeTrailing];
    [self.messageContentView autoPinEdge:ALEdgeTop toEdge:ALEdgeBottom ofView:self.headerLabel];
}

- (void)setupFooterLabel {

    //Setup Footer Label
    self.footerLabel = [[TTTAttributedLabel alloc] initForAutoLayout];
    self.footerLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Lato-Bold" size:10.0];
    self.footerLabel.textColor = FlatGray;
    self.footerLabel.backgroundColor = FlatGreen;
    self.footerLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
    self.footerLabel.textInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 8, 0, 8);
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.footerLabel];
    [self.footerLabel autoSetDimension:ALDimensionHeight toSize:10.0];
    [self.footerLabel autoPinEdgeToSuperviewEdge:ALEdgeLeading];
    [self.footerLabel autoPinEdgeToSuperviewEdge:ALEdgeTrailing];
    [self.footerLabel autoPinEdgeToSuperviewEdge:ALEdgeBottom];
    [self.footerLabel autoPinEdge:ALEdgeTop toEdge:ALEdgeBottom ofView:self.messageContentView];
}
```

**TextItem.m**

```
- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {

    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {

        //Setup Message Label
        [self setupMessageLabel];
    }

    return self;
}


#pragma mark - Setup Methods

- (void)setupMessageLabel {

    //Setup Message Label
    self.messageLabel = [[TTTAttributedLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 100)];
    self.messageLabel.verticalAlignment = TTTAttributedLabelVerticalAlignmentCenter;
    self.messageLabel.textInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(8, 8, 8, 8);
    self.messageLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    [self.messageContentView addSubview:self.messageLabel];

    //Update Label Color
    self.messageLabel.backgroundColor = FlatRed;
}

#pragma mark - Setter Methods

- (void)setMessageText:(NSString *)text {

    //Incoming Text Message
    NSMutableAttributedString *textString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text];
    [textString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor darkGrayColor] range:NSMakeRange(0, textString.length)];
    [textString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:16 weight:UIFontWeightLight] range:NSMakeRange(0, textString.length)];

    //Set Paragraph Style
    NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [NSMutableParagraphStyle new];
    paragraphStyle.minimumLineHeight = 20;
    paragraphStyle.maximumLineHeight = 20;
    [textString addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName value:paragraphStyle range:NSMakeRange(0, textString.length)];

    //Update Message Label
    [self.messageLabel setText:textString];

    NSLog(@"Set Message Label Text");
}

- (void)setMessage:(Message *)message {

    //Super
    [super setMessage:message];

    //Update Message Text
    [self setMessageText:message.text];
}
```

This is what my collectionView looks like:

[image]

I would at least expect the color of the messageLabel to reflect the change in TextItem, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you implement `initWithCoder`?

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)aDecoder 
{
    if(self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]) {
        // Do something
    }
    return self;
}
```

I don't have all your code, but you code looks good to me.  Maybe the problem was how you init the TextItem.

Here is a demo using your code, it works fine to me. https://www.dropbox.com/s/7qp9ayqnyacf57j/CustomCellView.zip?dl=0

Comment: I might be wrong but isn't `initWithCoder` only necessary if using storyboards? Also my `initWithFrame` is being called.

Comment: So every thing is written in code?  Could you show us how the MessageItem class is implemented?

Comment: And how did you init the TextItem?  When it shows up correctly and when it doesn't?

Comment: Just updated my answer with more details. Thanks for your time btw.

Comment: I don't see any red flag from the code, will get back to your later.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106522/discussion-between-dichen-and-kingpolygon).

Comment: Hi Dichen. I'm going to go ahead and close this, since I figured out the problem. I was accidentally registering the `MessageItem` class instead of the `TextItem` class. Oops. :( Such a noob mistake.

Comment: Actually I'll leave it open and accept your answer, since you do point out it could have been the way we init the class (in this case register it), and you did make an effort in helping. Thanks btw!